# Changing the keyboard layout turns off the numlock

Tags: xorg, keyboard-layout

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 with English and Greek keyboard layout and I have the following problem.

When I toggle  keyboard layouts (En->Gr or Gr->En) the num led turns off but I can print digits with the numeric keypad. So the numlock functions well but the led is off. This happens most of the times when I toggle keyboard layouts. 
Is there a way to separate num led status from keyboard toggling?

At this point, I would like to clarify that this happens only at Ubuntu unity version. When I tried xubuntu, kubuntu and other derivatives (linuxmint) the numlock led stays on when I toggle keyboard layouts.

Comment: What key combination do you use to toggle the layouts?

Comment: The default one: "Super+Space". I don't believe that the problem is a matter of key combination, because even if I change it to something else (ex. "Alt"+"Shift"), the behavior is the same. The num led turns off and if I press the toggle key combination repeatedly, sometimes it turns on, sometimes it turns off.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this is [a known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1247668) and the bug report includes a patch. You could try applying the patch and recompiling X or you could try this workaround:

1. Save this script as `~/bin/toggle_keyboard.sh`

   ```
   #!/bin/bash 

   current=`setxkbmap -query | grep layout | fold -s2 | tail -n 1`
   if [ "$current" == 'us' ]
   then
       setxkbmap -layout gr
   else
       setxkbmap -layout us
   fi
   ```
2. Make the script executable with `chmod +x ~/bin/toggle_keyboard.sh`.
3. Go to Settings => Keyboard => Shortcuts => Custom Shortcuts and assign create a shortcut that runs `/home/stelios/bin/toggle_keyboard.sh` (obviously, change `stelios` to whatever your actual username is).

You should now be able to use this new shortcut to toggle between your keyboard layouts.

Comment: I am afraid this solution doesn't solve the mentioned problem. Though I did as you instructed, I could change the keyboard layout, but:
1.The num led turned off 
2. The "flag" on the taskbar didn't change, so I couldn't know if my keyboard was in Greek or in English.

Comment: Further more: 3. Though the num led is off, the digits are all present, contrary to the bug you mentioned. I press 4 and I get a 4, I press 9 and I get a 9 (in the numeric keypad).

Comment: @SteliosSk yeah, I realized after posting. I had tested it and it worked but I then saw that it broke the flag. Strange about it's affecting the num led though, that will probably be fixed by a reboot. If you can live with not having the flag, try rebooting and it might be OK. An oxi, sorry, alla den exw tipota kalytero.

Comment: Anyway, thank you terdon for your willing to help! I admire your greeklish (Greek words typed with English letters).

Comment: @SteliosSk You might want to try applying the patch that is provided in the bug report I gave. Don't know if it's worth the effort but apparently that will solve it. Και ναι, ξέρω τι είναι τa Greeklish, Έλληνας είμαι βρε! :)

Comment: Γειά σου Έλληνα!
I am afraid I do not know how to apply the patch!!!
You see I am more of a GUI user :(

Comment: @SteliosSk it probably isn't worth it anyway. You'd need to get the source code, apply the patch and then recompile. Not worth the effort for what is a relatively minor bug.